# How do I convert a JScript Closure into a .NET delegate in JScript?

Tags: .net, delegates, closures, threadpool, javascript

I have a 'for' loop that has to transform stuff in thousands of files that don't depend on each other. The code is written in JScript. I would like to add some threading code to distribute the files among CPUs since the others appear to be idle. I'm trying to use the class System.Threading.ThreadPool, specifically the QueueUserWorkItem method, in JScript, but get an error at runtime that says:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.JScript.Closure' to type 'System.Threading.WaitCallback'.
```

Here is my code:

```
var conv = function MyConverter(arg1)
{
    // do the work
};

ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem( WaitCallback(conv) );
```

If I change my code to to call 'new WaitCallback(conv)' then I get this jsc.exe compiler error:

```
error JS1258: Delegates should not be explicitly constructed, simply use the method name
```

So I tried that with:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem( conv );
```

But then we are back to exact same InvalidCastException above.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that "global" functions cannot be used as delegates this way. This is a side effect of the fact that the delegates created from them are created using:

```
Delegate.CreateDelegate( Type, Object, String )
```

Where the second parameter "Object" is the instance of the object that the method will be invoked on.

You'll need to create a class to do what you are trying to do, something like:

```
import System;
import System.Threading;

class MyConverterClass
{
    function QueueUserWorkItem()
    {
        return ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(MyConverter);
    }

    function MyConverter()
    {
        print("Hello World.");
    }
}

// Example usage
var converter = new MyConverterClass();
converter.QueueUserWorkItem();
print("All done.");
```

This should compile and run fine, I used JSC 10.00.30319 to test it.

You can use the class instance to store whatever state you were planning on storing in the closure (if any) by creating a couple of instance variables in the class.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is there absolutely no way to do this the "JavaScript way" by having it inline?

Comment: I love JScript.Net but this is really tiresome.